# Keras (R): Remove layer after training

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Suppose I have fitted.trained my Keras model in R; for example say:

> ```
>      model<-keras_model_sequential()
>
>      model %>% layer_dense(units=5,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))%>% 
>
>      layer_dense(units=Height,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4)) %>%
>
>      model %>% layer_dense(units=1)
> ```

Once it is trained, is it possible to remove the last layer while keeping all else the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the layers separately first, you can then create a new model using the same layers:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

firstLayer <- layer_dense(units=5,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))
secondLayer <- layer_dense(units=Height,activation = "relu",input_shape = c(4))

model %>% firstLayer %>% 
secondLayer %>%
layer_dense(units=1)
```

The new model:

```
model2 <- keras_model_sequential()
model2 %>% firstLayer %>%
secondLayer
```

Comment: But after training the entire model (with both layers) how do I extract the first bunch (trianed)?  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You don't need to. `model2` contains the "very same" (trained) layers

Comment: If I use pop_layer can I store the last layer instead only deleting it?

Comment: I don't think pop is a very trustable thing. I prefer having more models, or using the functional API to create models that use smaller models so I can use all models independently and yet they all share and update the weights together.

Comment: WIth this `model` and `model2` approach, both models exist simultaneously, you can use any of them. If you train one, the other will update automatically (because in fact they have the same layers, not copies). Train `model`. Then when you don't want the last layer, start using `model2` (which is already trained). If you want the last layer again, go back to `model`, it's still there.